# Multidimensional Array from a txt file

Tags: c#

I need to create an 2D array from a text file.

my text file looks like this

```
Name1:Id1:Class1:Status1
Name2:Id2:Class2:Status2
```

and so on

I want my multidimensional array to make something like this

```
array = {{name1,id1,class1,status1},{name2,id2,class2,status2}}
```

I have seen other post related to it but non seems to be helping thats why posting again

Comment: Does all the rows contains all columns? (If not, you might want to choose a jagged array over a two dimensional array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that all of the lines have the same format. We can simply iterate through the lines as below:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
int len0 = lines.Length;
int len1 = lines[0].Split(':').Length;
string[,] array = new string[len0, len1];
for (int i= 0; i < len0; i++)
{
    string line = lines[i];
    string[] fields = line.Split(':');
    if (fields.Length != len1)
        continue; // to prevent error for the lines that do not meet the formatting
    for(int j = 0; j < len1; j++)
    {
        array[i,j] = fields[j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Going to a jagged array is pretty easy.  Going from a jagged array to a 2D array just requires some assumptions: like that all rows have the same number of items and that you know how many rows and columns there are when you create the array.

[string.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) will help you create the jagged array.  And a straightforward loop will help you create the multi-dimensional array.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string input = @"Name1:Id1:Class1:Status1
Name2:Id2:Class2:Status2";

        var jagged = input
                        .Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                        .Select(s => s.Split(':').ToArray())
                        .ToArray();

        var multi = new string[jagged.Length, jagged[0].Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < jagged.Length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < jagged[0].Length; ++j) {
                multi[i, j] = jagged[i][j];
                Console.WriteLine("[{0},{1}] = {2}", i, j, multi[i, j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And you can use File.ReadAllText to get it as a single big string with newlines intact, or File.ReadAllLines to read it split into an array of strings, one for each line as Ercan Peker already showed.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use a List object like code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<string>> data = new List<List<string>>();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string line = "";
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                List<string> lineArray = line.Split(new char[] { ':' }).ToList();
                data.Add(lineArray);
            }
            reader.Close();

        }
    }
}
```